# What does really the Java time in millis means?

Tags: java, date

Please need help to understand this small Java program showing two Java date with different values in long.

```
Date dateOne = new Date();
long dateOnetime = dateOne.getTime();

long dateTwoTime = dateOnetime / 1000;
dateTwoTime *=1000;

Date dateTwo = new Date(dateTwoTime);
```

When logging these variable with a simple System.out.println(String str); I got:

- dateOneTime         = 1476976051325
- dateTwoTime         = 1476976051000
- dateOne = dateTwo   = Thu Oct 20 16:07:31 WAT 2016

Why dateOneTime & dateTwoTime are so different but dateTwo is same as dateOne ??

Thanks in advance for clear details.

Comment: Because you only sees seconds in the date/time string and get rid of the milliseconds in dateTwoTime. Print both with format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS` and you will se the diference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Actually there is a difference at the millisecond level in your dates**. And that makes the difference.

dateOne and dateTwo are actually not equal. The fact is you are using the toString to assert the equality, which I believe is not the best way to go, because the **toString() doesn't take in account the millisecond difference**. I'd rather suggest you make use of the **dateOne.equals(dateTwo)** to make the comparison, as show in the sample I put for you here.

```
public class TestDate {

    public static void main (String ...args) {
            Date dateOne = new Date();
            long dateOneTime = dateOne.getTime();
            long dateTwoTime = dateOneTime/1000;

            System.out.println(dateOneTime);
            System.out.println(dateTwoTime);

            long dateThreeTime = dateTwoTime*1000;

            dateTwoTime *= 1000;

            System.out.println(dateThreeTime);
            System.out.println(dateTwoTime);
            Date dateTwo = new Date(dateTwoTime);
            if(dateOne.equals(dateTwo)) {
                    System.out.println("Dates are equal");
            } else {
                    System.out.println("Dates are not equal");
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and a direct example to use and see what I miss.
I set it as the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your two dates differ by less than 1 second or 1000 milliseconds (specifically, they differ by 325 milliseconds).

When you log them to only second precision (hours:minutes:seconds - 16:07:31), they will be displayed the same.

Answer (score 1):

Millis is [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) (1 second is 1000 millis)

Your two dates differ by less than 1 second or 1000 milliseconds

When you print them to hours:minutes:seconds format, they will be displayed as the same time.

Comment: Ok Thanks man for your response and clarification.
So a precision for the displayed date.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

You truncated the fractional second.

Same as doing this…

```
Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ).toEpochMilli()
```

## Details

You divided by one thousand, and then multiplied by one thousand on a count of [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond). You effectively truncated the fractional seconds from a date-time value defined as a count of [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) since the [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) of the first moment of 1970 in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (`1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`).

You are using a troublesome old date-time class, `java.util.Date`, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

The equivalent class in java.time is `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();  // Current moment in UTC.
```

To truncate any fractional second, do so by calling methods rather than using your math approach. This makes your code more self-documenting. And date-time work is tricky, so avoid roll-your-own solutions.

```
Instant instantWholeSeconds = instant.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS );
```

I strongly advise against tracking date-time values as a count-from-[epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)). It makes debugging difficult as humans cannot discern the date-time meaning from a very long integer. Furthermore, epochs vary with at least [a couple dozen in use by various systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing). And granularities of such counts vary, with various systems using whole seconds, [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond), [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond), [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), and other amounts as well. So count-from-epoch numbers are commonly ambiguous and prone to misinterpretation.

But if you insist, you can extract a count-from-epoch from an `Instant`. Remember that going to milliseconds as your count involves **data loss** as any nanoseconds will be truncated.

```
// WARNING: Data-loss. Truncating any nanoseconds. 
// CAUTION: Tracking date-time as count-from-epoch is *not* advised.
long millis = instant.toEpochMilli();
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).